# Listing contents of a directory using msbuild

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to debug an msbuild script that is being run on our TFS build agent. I have no permissions to the build agent server.

Is there a way I can add some debugging to my msbuild script ("Message" or similar) to output a listing of all the files in a given directory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2773088/62576 might help (see the accepted answer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hope this helps to list all the files in the folder where the MSBuild files are there recursively:

```
<Target Name="Listing">
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.*;"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="%(PackageFiles.FullPath)"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: What if I get directory from other include? For exaple: <ItemGroup>
  <EngineAssets Include="@(ProjectReference->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)$(AssetsDir)')" />
</ItemGroup>. I need to get files from folders in EngineAssets